# Value of $e-\int_{0}^{1}f(t)\,dt$

Tags: calculus

> Let $f:R^{+}\rightarrow R$ be a differentiable function satisfying $$\displaystyle f(x) = e+(1-x)(\ln(x)-1)+\int_{1}^{x}f(t)dt$$
>
> For all $x\in \mathbb{R^{+}}.$ Then value of $\displaystyle e-\int_{0}^{1}f(t)dt$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Using $$f'(x)=\frac{1-x}{x}+1-\ln x+f(x)$$

So we get $$f'(x)-f(x) = \frac{1}{x}-\ln x$$

So We get $$f(x)e^{-x} = \int \left(\frac{1}{x}-\ln x\right)e^{-x}dx = -\frac{e^{-x}}{x}+C$$

So we get $$f(x) = -\frac{1}{x}+Ce^{x}$$

Now Put $x=1\;, f(1)=e\;,$ We get $$C=1+\frac{1}{e}$$

So we get $$f(x) = -\frac{1}{x}+\left(1+\frac{1}{e}\right)e^{x}$$

Now $$e-\int_{0}^{1}f(t)dt = $$

Now I did not understand how can I Calculate $\ln(0)$ after integrating above function.

Help Required, Thanks

Comment: How did you computed that integral $ \int (1/x - ln(x)) e^{-x} $ ?

notice its actually $( ln(x)^\prime e^{-x} + ln(x) (e^{-x})^\prime ) = (ln(x)e^{-x})^\prime $

Comment: the $\int\left(\frac 1 x - \ln x\right)e^{-x} \, dx = e^{-x} \ln x$

Comment: Thanks   Francisco Jose Romero Hinrichs and abel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $g(x)=e^{-x}$, $f(x)=\ln x$, $$f(x) = \int \left(\frac{1}{x}-\ln x\right)e^{-x}dx=e^{-x}\ln x+C$$

$f(x)=Ce^x+\ln x$. Now, this may prove helpful-$$\int_{0}^{1} \ln x \mathbf{d}x =-\int_{-\infty}^{0}e^x \mathbf{d}x=-1$$ 
Which follows from the fact that $\ln x $ is the inverse of $e^x$.

Comment: actually that is a bit an overkill, it's just needed to see $f(x) = Ce^x + \log x$ and then substract the logarithm at the defining equation. Afterwards evaluate at 0.

Comment: @FranciscoJoseRomeroHinrichs What do you mean? How is this overkill? I only learned a bit of high-school integration, and I think what I am doing is within that boundary.

Comment: $\displaystyle f(x) = e+(1-x)(\ln(x)-1)+\int_{1}^{x}f(t)dt$ this was the first equation, afterwards you find f, the problem is to evaluate at 0, but the logarithms substract and the limit x\ln x goes to 0. then you get the value of the integral.

oh ok, about the overkill. Yeah could be, it didn't came instantly to use such a tool so I thougt it could be farfetched. Sorry if it sounded bad.